# How to Use gvNIX Menu Addon

Tags: gvnix

I have an application where a lot of the Menu items rendered are for administrative functions, so rather than having many links in my menu as it is now, I would like to move them into one Menu Item titled (Administration). I think that gvNIX menu add on may help me achieve this, but I have no idea what the steps and syntax would be to do this, and I cannot find documentation on this.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gvNIX/Roo console provides help for every command. You can view all commands typing `help` in the console. Moreover, if you type `help` + command, console shows info about that command like allowed parameters and short descriptions. In addition, pressing tab you can see suggestions for completing a Roo/gvNIX command.

That said, for achieve what you want you could use:

- `menu tree` for seeing the actual menu structure, with menu items id's.
- `menu entry add ...` for adding administration category in menu.
- `menu entry move ...` for moving desired menu entries to new category.

Hope that helps.